# How do I write React logs to CloudWatch securely using AWS SDK v3?

Tags: aws-sdk-js

I have a functional React logger that uses putLogEvents from AWS SDK v3 to write logs to CloudWatch using unauthenticated credentials. I'm wondering if it's possible (or does it matter) to use Cognito authentication to put these events? I thought I saw how to do so in some PDF docs and wrote some code to accomplish this but not sure if it's working or not - it's not throwing any errors, at least. Would love to know if anyone has any wisdom related to this - primarily:
A) Does it matter?
B) How can I check if my logs are being sent using authenticated credentials?
Ba) If they aren't being sent and it matters - what is the proper pattern for accomplishing secure logging in a React environment?

Currently I have a function that prepares the log event (and creates a logStream for the user session if one doesn't exist) and creates the client first using unauthenticated identity pool like so:

```
const client = new CloudWatchLogsClient({ 
  region: "xx-region-#",
  credentials: fromCognitoIdentityPool({
    client: new CognitoIdentityClient({ region: "xx-region-#" }),
    identityPoolId: config.Auth.identityPoolId,  
  }),
});
```

Then it uses the stored auth token to update the credentials like so:

```
  const {
    accessToken: { jwtToken, payload },
  } = await Auth.currentSession();

  let loginData = {
    [COGNITO_ID]: jwtToken,
   };
   
  const creds = fromCognitoIdentityPool({
    client: new CognitoIdentityClient({ region: "xx-region-#" }),
    identityPoolId: config.Auth.identityPoolId,
    logins: {
      loginData
    },
  })

  client.config.credentials = creds;
```

Thoughts anyone? Thank you!